# Theorem 11.43, Semimartingale Theory and Stochastic Calculus He, Wang and Yan 

Tags: stochastic-processes

Hallo,
does somebady know an easy proof of the following result?
If $X$ and $Y$ are independent Lèvy processes then their co-variation $[X,Y]$ is equal to zero.
One can find such a result without proof in He, Wang and Yan, Semimartingale Theory and Stochastic Calculus, Theorem 11.43. I have a proof of it but I feel that it is too complicated.
Thanks for help!!
Regards,
Paolo

Answer (score 1):

The co-variation is the unique continuous process of finite variation such that
$XY -[X,Y]$ is a martingale. It is therefore enough to verify that $XY$ is indeed a
martingale w.r.t. the filtration $\mathscr F(X) \vee \mathscr F(Y)$ generated by $X$ and $Y$. But this follows from properties the conditional expectation: The independence of
$\sigma(X_t) \vee \mathscr F(X)_s$ and $\sigma(Y_t) \vee \mathscr F(Y)_s$ yields
$$
E(X_tY_t | \mathscr F(X)_s \vee \mathscr F(Y)_s) = E(X_t | \mathscr F(X)_s ) E(Y_t | \mathscr F(Y)_s )=X_s Y_s.$$

EDIT: This argument works for *continuous* independent martingales.

Answer (score 0):

but XY does not need to be integrable if X and Y are Lèvy processes. Moreover, if XY is a martingale the co-variation is a martingale and not equal to zero.

Comment: By $[X,Y]$ I mean the process defined by
\[
[X,Y]_t:=\langle X^c,Y^c\rangle_t+\sum_{0<s\leq t}\Delta X_s\Delta Y_s.
\]
Sorry that I did not specify it before.